# Force.com upload file via API from guest user

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument, guest-user

I am building a visual force page that sends a file from the org to our 3rd party server that modifies the file as per instruction. So far that is working fine.

I need to return that document from my server back into my users files directory.

Problem is my server is not authenticated as the return can happen hours or even days later. So my server calls an apex class that I have exposed.

The file *does* get added but not to the user's org but some guest org and thus the file is not visible in the files tab.

Here is the code that is adding the file:

```
ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
    conVer.FirstPublishLocationId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    conVer.ContentLocation = 'S'; // S specify this document is in SF, use E for external files
    conVer.PathOnClient = 'testFile.pdf'; // The files name, extension is very important here which will help the file in preview.
    conVer.Title = Name; // Display name of the files
    conVer.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(Pdf64); // converting your binary string to Blog
    conver.Origin = 'C';

    conVer.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    insert conVer;

    // First get the content document Id from ContentVersion
    Id conDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:conVer.Id].ContentDocumentId;



    if(conDoc != null) {
        ContentDocumentLink cDe = new ContentDocumentLink();
                            cDe.ContentDocumentId = conDoc;
                            cDe.LinkedEntityId = returnedDoc.id; // you can use objectId,GroupId etc
                            cDe.ShareType = 'V'; // Inferred permission, checkout description of ContentDocumentLink object for more details
                            cDe.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
        insert cDe;
    }
```

How can I get the document into the files tab?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by user's org and guest org?  Do you mean specific account records?  Are these community users or standard license users?

Comment: So for now it's a development user. The user's org is the org that the authorized user has logged into. The guest org is the public access org which clearly doesn't have access the to authorized data that a logged in user has. I probably shouldn't be doing anonymous access but that leads to the question of how do I automatically authorize my server to work with SF without requiring physical user input?